# File can't be created

Tags: files

I'm having a very odd issue. I have a file that can't be created. No matter how I attempt to create a file with the name `libnss_dns-2.19.2f.so` in `/lib` the file doesn't exist. For example I tried running the following as root.

```
root@etmjenkins2:/lib# touch libnss_dns-2.19.2f.so
root@etmjenkins2:/lib# ll libnss_dns-2.19.2f.so
ls: cannot access libnss_dns-2.19.2f.so: No such file or directory
```

```
root@etmjenkins2:/lib# ls -ld /lib
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4096 Aug  7 17:06 /lib
root@etmjenkins2:/lib# mount
/dev/vda1 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
```

Note: This is on a digital oceans install.

Comment: What's the permission of `/lib`? `ls -ld /lib`. How's `/lib` mounted? How's `/` mounted? `mount`.

Comment: What happens when you do `sudo touch /lib/libnss_dns-2.19.2f.sX` ?

Comment: @K7AAY That works fine. Its only exactly `/lib/libnss_dns-2.19.2f.so` that has the problem

Comment: That quick test eliminates rights and mounting issues.